# ZeroMQ in javascript client

Tags: javascript, zeromq, channel

Have anyone used [ZmqSocket.js](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3ajavascript) successfully? I'd like to know how can it be used to establish a safe channel between the browser and a zeromq server app. Is there other/better options for such use case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've never used ZmqSocket.js, but I can tell you that it's probably not a good idea (yet). This is because zmq still assumes that both peers know the protocol well and will blow up if given invalid data (they are working on fixing that, though).

What I do right now is have a simple [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) based proxy that uses [socket.io](http://socket.io/) to communicate with browsers and pushes data in (and reads from) a zeromq socket, where the rest of the app is.

---

*Update in 2013:* I wrote [sockjsproxy](https://bitbucket.org/vladev/sockjsproxy/), which essentially proxies messages to/from [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) and zeromq, allowing you to implement the server in any language you want by just implementing the (very simple) ZeroMQ-based protocol.

I've personally used it with Python and Scala servers to build real-time web apps.

Answer (score 4):

I started looking into a solution to use a web browser for a UI.

I have a Java application that collects information from several sources, analyses it a stores the results in a database, allowing other systems to the information.

The Java app provides information (logs, events, and so on) on a PUSH ZMQ socket and provides a REP socket to control it (changing parameters, diagnosis requests, etc).

I currently have a Python app with a UI using Tk and I plan to replace it with a web interface.

The problem I have with the ZMQ JavaScript biding is that it uses a flash component, which is not supported by iOS.

Doing a bit of Googoling I found a post titled "[Interacting With ZeroMQ From the Browser](http://avalanche123.com/blog/2012/02/25/interacting-with-zeromq-from-the-browser/)" that uses [NullMQ](https://github.com/progrium/nullmq)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective: implementing a WebSocket-to-ZeroMQ proxy that handles *all* of ZeroMQ's strategies seems like a lot of work, but you can very quickly get a partial proxy running. Like Emil, I'm experimenting with a PyZMQ <--Tornado--> WebSocket bridge; in my case I only care about getting messages from SUB sockets.

In my model, I send JSON messages from the browser to the proxy, requesting the creating of new ZMQ sockets. When these sockets receive data, they send it back to the browser over the same WebSocket connection.

Here's the [python proxy backend](https://github.com/justjake/squidwork/blob/master/squidwork/web/socket.py), and my [javascript proxy frontend](https://github.com/justjake/squidwork/blob/master/squidwork/web/templates/squidwork.coffee#L83). In my Python code, the `AsyncReciever` class is a very thin wrapper around a `ZMQStream` that basically runs JSON encode/decode. If you want to send raw ZeroMQ bytes to the browser, things would be even easier: just connect a `ZMQSocket.on_message` callback directly to `BridgeWebSocket.write_message`.