# Choosing protocols for communication with clients for server application in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, client-server, messaging

I need to write server application that interacts with 3 types of clients: desktop app, mobile app and web front-end. Maximum number of concurrent connections would be 2 or 3 thousand. The approximate exchange format:

1. Desktop app (written in Python + PyQt)

   a) Client: Data request
      Server: Data response

   b) Server: Notify
      Client: Acknowledge
2. Mobile app (Android):

   a) Client: Send data
      Server: Acknowledge

   b) Server: Notify
      Client: Acknowledge
3. Web front-end:

   a) Client: Data request
      Server: Data response

Data is selections from SQL and contains order info, customer info, gps data etc. I am planing to use json for data serialization, but I don't quite understand which underlying protocol and extensions should I chose.
In case of front-end I want to use Tornado and implement the RESTfull api. I know, that it can be also used for other types of clients, but is implementing server to client messaging with Tornado a good idea? Maybe it is better to implement this with ZeroMQ (or another messaging system) or use raw TCP sockets? And how about Tulip, should I use it instead of Tornado?

Comment: Related: [ZeroMQ in javascript client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8145060/95735)